# Processing SAP IDoc files in Azure Synapse/Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, idoc

I'm looking for a way to process SAP IDoc files via Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse pipeline. The solution should be capable of extracting data from the raw files taken from the SFTP (in IDoc format) and writing the processed data to a SQL Database. I know there are SAP connectors available, but the issue is that the files (IDocs) should be extracted not from the SAP system directly but rather from the SFTP folder in which they're stored in thousands daily. I'm not an expert in Azure Data Factory/Synapse, but these services allow to build a descent processing pipeline for all sorts of ETL processing. So, I wonder if they can also handle the data parsing or if I'm looking at the wrong place.
Please advice.

Comment: For information, there are 3 standard SAP IDoc formats: an old plain text format (before IDoc 4.0), plain text, XML. I hope it's standard XML, otherwise it will be very difficult to parse them without the help of SAP software.

Comment: Support Sandra point, it worth checking which particular IDoc format is used in your scenarion and then start from that